# Javascript toggle menu collapsed issue

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle

I have created a Javascript toggle menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
            $(this).next().slideUp("fast");

        } else {
            $('.toggle').next().slideUp("fast").removeClass("expanded");
            $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
            $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
            $(this).addClass("expanded");
        }
    });
});
```

When I click on another item in the menu, the class "expanded" is not removed from the other elements. I've tried many different things but can't get my head around it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
            $(this).next().slideUp("fast");
            $(this).addClass('collapsed');
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
            var $expandedItems = $('.expanded');
            $expandedItems.next().slideUp("fast")
            $expandedItems.addClass('collapsed');
            $expandedItems.removeClass('expanded');
            $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
            $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
            $(this).addClass("expanded");
        }
    });
});
```

Based on your comments I think you are after something like this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.toggle').click(function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("expanded")) {
            $(this).next().slideUp("fast");

        } else {
            $('.expanded').removeClass('expanded');//here is your problem
            $(this).next().slideDown("fast");
            $(this).removeClass("collapsed");
            $(this).addClass("expanded");
        }
    });
});
```

This should be remove expanded class from your jquery code

Note Tested although please tell me if its not working

updated

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/luismruiz/YRVev/)

And for jquery i think you are missing too much information here check demo  here [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CShsY/4/)

Comment: That solution doesn't collapse the other items when another one is clicked and doesn't add a "collapsed" class to the item when it's clicked again.

Comment: but you don't addding collpsed class any where ? how this will possible

Comment: The items are already called "collapsed", so "expanded" replaces that class name when it's clicked. All I need to do is add "collapsed" to the items when another item is clicked.

Comment: Please check my updated solution i think you are missing too much here